# Find file within directory and delete the directory its in

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, directory, find, delete-file

Is there a command for windows batch files that enables me to find a file and then delete the directory that it is in? This would also mean deleting all the files in the directory with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /s /b "c:\startingdirname\targetfilename"') DO ECHO RD /s /q "%%~dpi"
```

Should accomplish this task. You'd need to supply your drive, starting directoryname (to start the scan) and filename, of course.

This will merely `ECHO` the directoryname that is selected. To activate, remove the `ECHO` keyword after carefully veryifying that it's what you want to do.

And this is intended as a line in a batch file. To use directly from the prompt, reduce each `%%` to `%`

Answer (score 0):

%~dp1 can be used to convert a file param to a drive and path.  Quote the output as it doesn't convert to 'safe' path names.

[SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) is a great resource for learning command scripting.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work

You need to find file manualy and then deleting it's directory which is in path. If you don't know exact location of file you need to go in root directory i. e. C:> and then type command as
e.g.
C:>dir file_name.* /s

after this you will get whole path

C:>del directory_name.*